# GPUImage2: captureAsYUV parameter impact on Camera

Tags: ios, camera, compatibility, gpuimage, yuv

Up to now, I've kept the default value for captureAsYUV parameter, which is true.

I have a system to live switch between 15 filters. Because I sometimes have some crash (Bad Access) when I switch filters quickly and for a long time, I looked at this property.

After init the camera obj setting captureAsYUV to false, I noticed that I can't reproduce such a crash. But while it works fine on front camera, previewing with back camera is a mess, with colored stripes and "broken" image. I think I will use true for back camera and false for front one.

What is the impact to use captureAsYUV = false ?

Are there any compatibility risks with some iOS devices (and get same result on front camera as on Back camera)?